# how to record everything from a web application with call flow diagrams in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a requirement to record web application which contains process of creating call flow diagrams, i want to record all the steps involved and execute the same.

I know how to record in JMeter , Please help me providing inputs for recording a call flow diagram of a web application and emulate the same process from jmeter.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BlazeMeter Chrome Extension and record the flow. Create an account in [blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/record-and-edit-jmeter-script-without-using-jmeter-blazemeters-chrome-extension) and login so that you can export the recorded steps as a .jmx file using the above extension. Next, you can open the .jmx which were exported in JMeter and edit the recorded flow to get it work.